# Why is every algebraically closed field perfect?

Tags: field-theory

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, and google has been surprisingly unhelpful. I don't intuitively see why a field being algebraically closed means that every irreducible polynomial over that field must have distinct roots.

Comment: Look up your definitions. $X^2$ has a double root over _any_ field.

Comment: sorry, I meant every *irreducible* polynomial, of course

Comment: Hint: the only irreducible polynomials over an algebraically closed field are linear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over an algebraically closed field the only irreducible polynomials are those of degree$~1$. They obviously cannot have multiple roots.